# Split framework.jar into smaller jar files

Tags: android, frameworks, android-source

I met this error when i built my modified Android source. (version 4.1.1_r6)

> Dex framework 
>   [dx] trouble writing output: Too many methods: 65867; max is 65536. By package:

I know the solution for this problem is that spliting framework into smaller package files to reduce the number of methods in framework.jar. It requires some modifications in .mk files but Android make file system is quite complicated. 
 
I hope that anybody give me some instructions to do that. 
Thanks